# Manually trigger an event on window object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a listener like so:

```
    window.addEventListener('native.showkeyboard', function (e) {
        ...
        ...
    });
```

I'm writing a unit test for this so I want to trigger the event. Im doing:

```
    window.trigger('native.showkeyboard');
```

But I end up with an error for that line saying:

```
    undefined is not a function
```

How can I manually trigger this event?

**EDIT**

I have also tried:

```
  $(window).trigger('native.showkeyboard');
```

but the handler doesnt run with this as it's not registered with jquery...

Comment: `$(window).trigger("native.showkeyboard")`. But IIRC, your handler will not run because it was registered through `addEventListener()`, not through jQuery's own registration system.

Comment: ya you are right, the handler doesnt run

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are triggering the event via `jQuery` then the event ought to have been attached via `jQuery` -- see @fredericHamidi's comment.

```
$(window).on('native.showkeyboard', function (e) {
    .........
});

$(window).trigger('native.showkeyboard');
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/H7MR7/)

Or if you're using plain vanilla JS do it this way:

```
window.addEventListener('native.showkeyboard', function (e) {
    ........
});

window.dispatchEvent( new Event('native.showkeyboard') );
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/H7MR7/2/)

Comment: how do i trigger event without jquery?

Comment: You can use: `window.dispatchEvent( new Event('native.showkeyboard') );` -- http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/H7MR7/2/

Answer (score 0):

well you are not working with a jQuery object...That would be your problem.

```
 window.trigger('native.showkeyboard');  //<-- window is not a jQuery object
```

You need to wrap it

```
 $(window).trigger('native.showkeyboard');
```